# full calendar - associate clickable icons with events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I want to append 4 icons each event on the calendar. Each icon should calls different function on click event. To be honest, I am not too good in CSS. I have tried the below code but the click event for these icon is not invoked. Instead events event is invoked. Is there anyway to append 4 icons with clickable event? Thank you in advance

```
eventRender: function(event,element,calEvent) {
    element.find(".fc-event-title").after($("<span class=\"fc-event-icons\"></span>").html("<img src=\"/images/pass.png\" onclick=\"javascript:icons("+this.id+");\" /><img src=\"/images/pass.png\" onclick=\"javascript:icons("+this.id+");\" /><img src=\"/images/pass.png\" onclick=\"javascript:icons("+this.id+");\" /><img src=\"/images/pass.png\" onclick=\"javascript:icons("+this.id+");\" />"));
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to use the `.on()` function to register an event handler to your icons.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/rpc23/

The click events get triggered and are handled appropriately with the `.on()` handler. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: @ganeshk I had used the .on() function to make the icons clickable but the issue is when I click on the icon the eventClick method of the fullcalendar plugin is also triggerd. I dont want the eventClick method to be triggered when I click on the icon that is placed on the event. Can you please shade some light on this?

Comment: Could you add the fiddle code into your answer? the jsfiddle is having stability issues at least for me and some other Brazilian users

Comment: Hi @ganeshk can you please update the fiddle with latest jquery and fullcalendar, because with new version its not working please check if you can update?...