# Add image to an event - Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I have a json file with events, which are loaded in fullcalendar.js . I want to add an image to each event (before the timestamp of the event). I already looked up a solution on here: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537525/full-calendar-associate-clickable-icons-with-events/), but it didn't give me the answer because I think fullcalendar updated after that.

I like to know these things:

First of all: the 'img src' attribute, do I need to reference path from my HTML file or javascript file?

Second: I think the .fc-event-title tag was removed from the CSS file, because I can't seem to find in the CSS file.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I make it in the eventRender function (in json i have a event.icon):

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

        if(event.icon){
            if(event.allDay){
                $(element).find('span:first').prepend('<img src="./fileadmin/images/layout/'+event.icon+'" />');
            }else{
                $(element).find('.fc-time').prepend('<img src="./fileadmin/images/layout/'+event.icon+'" />');
            }
        }
    },
```

And your second que:
Yes i have updated fullcalendar too, and some class names changed to a shorter version.